# Functionality of iloc and simply [ ] in a series

Tags: pandas, data-science, data-analysis

I think in pandas a series S
S[0:2]  is equivalent to s.iloc[0:2] , in both cases two rows will be there but recently I got into a trouble [The first picture shows the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxWPm.png)   but I didn't know what went wrong in the [In this picture S[0] is showing error i don't know why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBy0e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can try to explain this behavior a bit. In Pandas, you have selection by `position` or by `label`, and it's important to remember that every single row/column will always have a `position` "name" and a `label` name. In the case of columns, this distinction is often easy to see, because we usually give columns string names. The difference is also obvious when you use explicitly `.iloc` vs `.loc` slicing. Finally, `s[X]` is **indexing**, which `s[X:Y]` is **slicing**, and the behaviour of the two actions is different.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b': [3,3,4]})
df.iloc[:,0]
df.loc[:,'a']
```

both will return

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Now, what happened in your case is that you overwrote the index names when you declared `s.index = [11,12,13,14]`. You can see that by inspecting the index before and after this change. Before, if you run `s.index`, you see that it is a `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)`. After you change the index, it becomes `Int64Index([11, 12, 13, 14], dtype='int64')`.

Why does this matter? Because although you overrode the `labels` of the index, the position of each one of them remains the same as before. So, when you call

```
s[0:2]
```

you are slicing *by position* ([this section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#slicing-ranges) in the documentation explains that it's equivalent to `.iloc`. However, when you run

```
s[0]
```

Pandas thinks you want to select by `label`, so it starts looking for the `label` 0, which doesn't exist anymore, because you overrode it. Think of the square-bracket selection in the context of selecting a dataframe column: you would say `df["column"]` (so you're asking for the column by `label`), so the same is in the context of a series.

In summary, what happens with Series indexing is the following:

- In the case you use **string index labels**, and you index by an `string`, Pandas will look up the string label.
- In the case you use **string index labels**, and you index by an `integer`, Pandas will fall back to indexing by position (that's why your example in the comment works).
- In the case you use **integer index labels**, and you index by an `integer`, Pandas will **always** try to index by the "label" (that's why the first case doesn't work, as you have overriden the `label` 0).

Here are two articles explaining this bizarre behavior:

[Indexing Best Practices in Pandas.series](https://towardsdatascience.com/indexing-best-practices-in-pandas-series-e455c7d2417)

[Retrieving values in a Series by label or position](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781787123137/3/ch03lvl1sec27/retrieving-values-in-a-series-by-label-or-position)

Comment: but when I again change the indexes using s.index = ['hi','hello','i','my']   ,I see that the index is a  ** Index(['hi', 'hello', 'my', 'I'], dtype='object') **   and  s[0] should give error as you said pandas will look for label 0 which doesn't exist, but that doesn't happen and I get the value for s[0] without any errors

Comment: Hi @PrashantJoshi, I updated my answer to explain that how pandas interprets the indexing will depend on whether your data has `integer` or `string` labels. I suppose it's because of all this unexpected behavior that they always recommend using `.iloc` and `.loc` explicitly.